# How to add a hidden field to all simple_form generated forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How to add a hidden field tag to all simple_form generated forms in Rails 3.2?

Or how can I add a hidden input field to all forms (both form_for and form_tag generated forms)?

I'm asking to do it in a generic way, I have hundreds of such forms and I want to add in all of them, not just single form.

I am expecting something involving form builders, I tried them but I am not getting it right.

Comment: my guess would be to override simple_form or form_for tags, with calling super after you got everything you need

Comment: Yes, thats the idea but can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You should look for simple_form_for method in your gem, to understand how it works. Then you can write method with the same name, but adding some other code, that will insert hidden field for each item. After that you need to call `super` so the parent method could be called